# Creating a .jar file which includes other .jar files?

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to make a .jar file (this is my first time) and I'm confused. I understand how to use command prompt to create a simple jar file, but for my program I import the JavaMail API and another library which I created (called ArrayLibrary filled with sorting methods). How would I create these all in one jar file?

I've read about jarSplice, but is that the right tool to be using for this problem?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse its as easy as right clicking your project -> export -> Java -> JAR file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including libraries in jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764834/including-libraries-in-jar)

Answer (score 2):

This question gets asked frequently, so should technically be marked as a duplicate, but looking at the previous questions, I wasn't able to find a suitably comprehensive answer. So, here's my attempt at providing one:

Firstly, the Java specs don't allow for embedding jar files within other jar files.
There are some projects out there that provide specialized classloaders to allow this, but none that I'm aware of work in all situations.

As background, a .jar file is actually a .zip that contains java class files and resources, in the same tree-structure as you'd find in the file system if you hadn't jar'd them. You can create a .jar file with the 'jar' utility or any zip utility - just rename the .zip file to .jar, and it should work fine.

So, the answer is to expand (un-jar, unzip) all of your jar files into a directory structure, and then jar them back up. Your new jar file will then contain all of the artifacts from all of your original jar files.

The problem with doing this manually, besides it being fairly tedious, is that multiple jar files may contain resources of the same name (for instance, a MANIFEST.MF file). You'd  probably have to manually combine the manifests to keep things working properly.

So, a number of tools have been created to automate this. JarSplice seems to be one of these, though I've never heard of it before, so can't say whether it works well or not.

My personal recommendation is a bit involved, but has other benefits:
Create a [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) build for project. Then add the [maven-assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies) to your project, and use it to build the one big jar (known as an UberJar).

The additional benefits are that you now have a solid build system for your project, you are no longer dependent on your IDE to build your project, and other people (or you, later) can build your project in a standard way, without requiring the use of a particular IDE.

There may be something similar for Gradle, or there may be a way to use Maven plugin with Gradle, but I haven't researched that.

While I wouldn't recommend it, you can also do this with Ant and it's UberJar plugin.